# pip install py2neo failing

Tags: python, neo4j, pip, py2neo

I am trying to install py2neo module but ending with below error. Please help me to resolve it.

```
(base) C:\Users\ADMIN>pip install py2neo Collecting py2neo   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/79/a77cc0ad86c021c25dac9f52a0cd33f6832c6af7fa5e58f4438d781ae9c3/py2neo-4.0.0.tar.gz
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-xj8t67\py2neo\setup.py", line 25, in <module>
    from py2neo.meta import __author__, __email__, __license__, __package__, __version__
  File "py2neo\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from py2neo.data import *
  File "py2neo\data.py", line 26, in <module>
    from py2neo.cypher import LabelSetView, cypher_repr, cypher_str
  File "py2neo\cypher\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from py2neo.internal.collections import SetView
  File "py2neo\internal\collections.py", line 24, in <module>
    from py2neo.internal.compat import bytes_types, string_types
  File "py2neo\internal\compat.py", line 45, in <module>
    DEVNULL = open(devnull, "rw")
ValueError: Invalid mode ('rw')

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-xj8t67\py2neo\
```

I tried to upgrade setuptools and pip too but didn't able to install py2neo after that also.

My python version is 2.7 and working on win 10 OS.

Comment: From the README: "Note also that Py2neo is developed and tested under Linux using standard CPython distributions. While other operating systems and Python distributions may work, support for these is not available."

Answer (score 1):

try this as well :

This is the basic requirements :

Python 2.7 / 3.4 / 3.5 / 3.6 / 3.7
Neo4j 3.2 / 3.3 / 3.4 / 3.5 (the latest point release of each version is recommended)

```
pip install git+https://github.com/technige/py2neo.git#egg=py2neo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the library. It is illegal to open a file with mode `"rw"`, and they're clearly doing it. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/technige/py2neo/blob/v4/py2neo/internal/compat.py#L41). It should almost certainly be using `"r+"` here.

---

It's worth noting that this piece of code only runs on old versions of Python, before `subprocess.DEVNULL` was added in 3.3. While 2.7 is still listed as officially supported, it seems to be in "legacy mode", with a bunch of "compat" code that tries to make 2.7 act like 3.3+, including this line, and some of that compat code is probably not heavily tested.

Also, this piece of code may only be needed on Windows. If so, as the README says:

> Note also that Py2neo is developed and tested under Linux using standard CPython distributions. While other operating systems and Python distributions may work, support for these is not available.

So, the fact that their 2.7 compat code is broken on a platform they don't support isn't all that surprising…

---

What can you do about it?

- Try running Python 3.7 or 3.6 instead of 2.7. That will definitely eliminate this problem, and possibly others that you haven't run into yet.
- Run a linux VM (/container/user-mode kernel/whatever), and install Python (ideally 3.7) and py2neo under linux. This will definitely eliminate this problem, and possibly others.
- Fix the bug yourself and submit a pull request.
- File a bug report and wait and see if someone fixes it.

Comment: Thank you @abarnet , will follow these instructions.